# Generating a large matrix from smaller matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a directory `matrix` that contains a series of text file matrices of 0s and 1s of varying sizes which look like:

```
txt.1
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 0 1
txt.2
1 1 0
0 1 1
txt.3
1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

I am trying create a larger diagonal matrix from these smaller matrices that replaces all the values in the smaller matrices with 0 and fills in the empty spaces in the diagonal with 1s so that the final result looks like:

```
print(bigmatrix)
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Is there some way to use `bdiag` or some other function here?  I have only been able to get `bigdiag` to fill in everything with 0s.

Comment: Can you clarify the connection between the small matrices and the "big matrix"? At the moment the number of rows in the small matrices has no connection with he rows in the big matrix. Are you asking that we take `max( dim(.) )` for the size of the zero-square-blocks?

Comment: Ncol and Nrow of big matrix equals to sum of number of columns in smaller ones

Comment: @BondedDust I didn't quite understand your question, but basically I am using the sizes of the smaller matrices in the order in which they are found in the directory to place them along the diagonal of the larger matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the elements of each small matrix, just create N matrices filled with 1's and dimension of `max(dim(mx))`

```
m1 = matrix(1,3,3)
m2 = matrix(1,3,3)
m3 = matrix(1,4,4)

lst = list(m1,m2,m3)
print(lst)
m0 = as.matrix(bdiag(lst))
m0 = ifelse(m0 == 0, 1, 0)
View(m0)
```

Result:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
5   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
6   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
7   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
8   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
9   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
10  1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works:

```
library(Matrix)
library(MASS)
structural0<-lapply(dir(), function(x){as.matrix(read.table(x))})
structural0<-lapply(structural0,function(x){ifelse(x==0,1,1)})
structural0<-bdiag(structural0)
write.matrix(structural0, file="structural0.txt")
structural0a<-as.matrix(read.table("structural0.txt"))
structural0a<-ifelse(structural0a==0,1,0)
write.matrix(structural0a, file="structural0a.txt")
```

However, I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing it.  Thank you.